# Julia Plots xtick and ytick font halign and valign

Tags: julia, plots.jl, julia-plots

I am trying to understand the behavior of certain keyword arguments in the default GR backend for the Julia Plots package. Here is a screen shot that explains what is going on:

[image: alignment reversed]

I have looked at the documentation for the Plots.jl package and I can't find the reason behind this behavior. Is this a documented bug?

Next, why does the spacing between the tick labels and the axis itself depend on the grid sizing? Here is another image:

[image: Spacing increased]

As you can see, the default spacing between the y-axis and the tick labels has magically gained a minimum setting/default. One can verify that that this *minimum gap* actually increases with **grid size**, in other words the minimum spacing increases with `N` for grid sizes `N x N`. I have been unable to get rid of this gap (tried the `*align`, `*fontsize`, `*_margin`, `size` and `dpi` keywords).

Can anyone let me know how to get around this?

Comment: if this is indeed a bug, perhaps posting it on [the Github](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues) would be the best bet?

Comment: it is quite odd, and I can't imagine it being an intended feature